# Unable to replace blank box with blank space

Tags: python

I am trying to make it to where any spaces are not encrypted as blank boxes because the blank boxes do not convert in every messaging app.

I have tried doing an if statement inside the first for loop and my current attempt is putting it in it's own for loop.

```
    if choice == '1':
        message = input('\nEnter message for encryption: \n')
        for i in range(0, len(message)):
            result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

        for i in range(0, len(result)):
            if result[i] == '':
                result[i] = result[i].replace('', ' ')
        print(result + '\n\n')
        result = ''
```

I am currently getting an issue where there is a type error, but I'm confused as to why this is. It should produce the encrypted version with spaces instead of squares.

The squares aren't showing up on here either, so I'm putting in a picture as reference:
[image: empty square boxes]

Current error code: result[i] = result[i].replace('', ' ')
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Reproducted sample:

Hello World
Encrypted: FcjjmUmpjb
[image: Hello World with empty boxes]

Comment: What are you talking about with "blank boxes" and "squares"?  And is the actual error reported?

Comment: Note to readers that are as confused as I was: the OP's code seemingly appears to use the empty string `''`, but actually it is a string literal with length 1 and ordinal value 30. Seems like Stack Overflow refuses to render it, but it's there. You can see it if you click "edit".

Comment: Please read this link on how to create a [mcve] and edit your question with sample input and desired output

Comment: My apologies, I thought the empty boxes would show up here, but I was incorrect. I have placed 2 pictures to attempt to supplement my problem and try to understand it.

Comment: You can just do ``result.replace('\x1e', ' ')``.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to create a Caesar Cipher that shifts every character backwards by two, but you want spaces to stay the same. Makes sense, because the character two away from space is a control character that doesn't even render on lots of platforms.

Your second loop is trying to reassign characters in `result` by replacing chr(30) with space. But if `result` is a string, this won't work, because strings are immutable and indexed assignment on strings is not legal. Instead, try just doing a single `replace` call on the entire string.

```
result = ""
message = "Hello world"
for i in range(0, len(message)):
    result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

result = result.replace(chr(30), " ")
print(result + '\n\n')
```

Result:

```
Fcjjm umpjb
```

---

Alternatively, don't call replace, just don't bother shifting in the first place if the character is a space.

```
result = ""
message = "Hello world"
for i in range(0, len(message)):
    if message[i] == " ":
        result = result + " "
    else:
        result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

print(result + '\n\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I thought I had to loop through it

Comment: Do you happen to know why, instead of a blank box, it now leaves behind "" where spaces should be?